# Identify two digits in a cell are both odd or both even

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need your help on the following:

I have a number of records in two digit format.
For these I want to verify for the two separate digits to either both be even, or both be odd.

The purpose is to have a conditional formatting rule set for both being odd and another for both being even.

Please find some sample data below:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **13** | 29 | **91** | 98 | 34 | *42* |
| 32 | 16 | 18 | **57** | *80* | *20* |
| *02* | *02* | **51** | **31** | *64* | **13** |
| 50 | 25 | 47 | 54 | 32 | 41 |

As you can see some numbers are marked bold. These numbers consist of 2 odd digits;
others are marked italic. These consist of 2 even digits.

*Example:*

`13` consist of `1` and `3`; both these numbers are odd. This should be formatted `red` (for example).

`29` consists of `2` and `9`; `2` being even, but `9` being odd. This should not be formatted.

`42` consists of `4` and `2`; both being even numbers. This should be formatted `green` (as an example)

I have no clue how to separate the check of the single digits within the same cell.

Comment: Is each number in a cell? What does identifying in your case mean i.e. what is the expected result?

Comment: only two digit in one cell

Comment: but both digit odd or even i want identified

Comment: @VBasic2008 understand my point?

Comment: @VBasic2008 if both digit odd then color red or both digit even color green

Comment: The format is two digits ok. The values are numbers or string?

Comment: yes two digit format value is number

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you have run into problems. You can certainly use conditional formatting for this kind of issue.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld conditional formula only work on particular number but i want differentiate two digit.  ex. =ISEVEN(A1)

Comment: Get the digits with left(), mid() or right() then do a simple test like left(a1,2)*1=even(a1)

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. Do you mean to check the individual digits that are part of a cell to both be odd? In that case this could work `=AND(ISODD(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$2),1)))`

Comment: @P.b simple my question i have two digit number ex 13 so first is 1 and second is 3 how identified both digit odd?

Comment: I edited your question to include what you commented and for better readability.

Comment: Also, don't tag both Excel and Google sheets. They're different and the solutions may not work on the other platform. Make up your mind what you want to use as a platform.

Comment: You just check one digit at a time, and `AND` the results

Answer (score 3):

**both digits in cell are odd**

This checks the first and second digit in a cell to be odd:
`=AND(ISODD(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$2),1)))`

Or shorter, as suggested by VBasics2008 (thanks!):
`=AND(ISODD(--MID(A1,{1;2},1)))`

**2 digits in cell are both either odd or even**

In your question you formatted both numbers that had both digits odd and also the ones that had both even. In that case use `=SUM(MOD(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$2),1),2))<>1`

Or `=SUM(MOD(--MID(A1,{1;2},1),2))<>1`

**Both digits in cell are even**

If you want a separate for both being even, use `=AND(ISEVEN(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$2),1)))`

Or `=AND(ISEVEN(--MID(A1,{1;2},1)))`

Comment: Instead of `ROW($1:$2)`, couldn't you just use `{1;2}`? Pointing out the real answer (*2 digits...*) and adding the rule that the sum of two even or the sum of two odd numbers is an even number would make it a great answer.

Comment: @VBasic2008 : :-) see my answer before I saw OP wanted it separately, where I proposed a solution based on the fact that the sum of both digits of the “same kind” is always even (and also avoiding the use of string operation)

Comment: @VBasic2008 even though `{1;2}` might be shorter and even better, given that an array separator may differ for different system languages, the solution as is seems more "dummy"-proof. So even though you're totally right, I'm not going to implement it to my answer.
What exactly do you mean by adding a rule that sum of two odds is an even? Are you talking about my SUM MOD <>1-solution?

Comment: The initial question was rather unclear, while in the end it was an interesting case.

Comment: Someone wrote that both, the row and the column separators, depend on the Windows Regional Settings. I'm not sure if that's entirely true. I know there are different column separators that depend on the Excel decimal separator and the WRS, from the default comma to a `.`, a \, a `@`,...etc.  But have ever heard of someone having a different **row** separator than a semicolon? BTW, how can you even change these two separators?

Comment: I know in my native language settings (Dutch) the semicolon is not a row separator, but a column separator. That would not make a difference to the outcome of these formulas though. Since we sum them it doesn't matter if it's horizontally or vertically. Added it as a suggestion, since I'm unaware of the possible other language separators.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this should work to check both digits are odd or even:

```
=OR(AND(ISEVEN(QUOTIENT(A1,10)),ISEVEN(MOD(A1,10))),AND(ISODD(QUOTIENT(A1,10)),ISODD(MOD(A1,10))))
```

**Explanation:**

- A1 is here the cell with the 2 digit number
- Just divide the number by 10 via **QUOTIENT** and **MOD** to separate the
  respective digits.
- check the conditions with **ISEVEN** and **ISODD** accordingly

**Edit:**

A shorter version to check both digits are odd or both are even:

```
=ISEVEN(SUM(QUOTIENT(A1,10),MOD(A1,10)))
```

**Edit2:**

Use the respective AND() sections of the first formula to check for even or odd separately (missed your comment earlier)

btw, this solution does not require any string operation on the number

Comment: I do like the use of `QUOTIENT` in this case. Creative.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in comments: "if both digit odd then color red or both digit even color green"

So you need two conditional formating rules. One for the red and one for the green.

WHEN THE TWO DIGITS ARE ODD THE NEXT FORMULA IS TRUE

```
=(MOD(LEFT(TEXT(A1;"00");1);2) + MOD(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"00");1);2))=2
```

WHEN THE TWO DIGITS ARE EVEN THE NEXT FORMULA IS TRUE

```
=AND(A1<>"";(MOD(LEFT(TEXT(A1;"00");1);2) + MOD(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"00");1);2))=0)
```

Use them accordingly. Change the ; with , according your local settings.
I modify the even formula to return FALSE on empty cells and remain without color. The formulas don't returm error on empty cells.

**A second approach:** (If cell is empty both return false)

true if digits are odd:

```
=MOD(INT(A1/10);2)+MOD(A1;2)=2
```

true if digits are even:

```
=AND(A1<>"";MOD(INT(A1/10);2)+MOD(A1;2)=0)
```